# Caching in custom ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I would like to be able to specify a cache duration on my own action filter's OnActionExecuting method.

Whilst I was able to decorate my method with the built-in `System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute` attribute it didn't work. I take it the use-case for these is purely in a controller's action methods.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  //some code here
}
```

So in terms of caching within a custom action filter, what are the best practices?

Comment: I feel like if you need to do this, you implemented some of the MVC concepts incorrect. Can you provide more details on why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything out-of-the-box in ASP.NET MVC for this. You can use `System.Web.Caching.Cache` class and develop your own solution.

```
var cache = new Cache();

// Set cache value: 
cache.Add("YourKey", "YourData", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(300), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

// Get cache value:
var value = cache["YourKey"];
```

Comment: thanks, just wanted to check that there wasn't something else built in.